# Position text so that it appears inside an image

Tags: html, css, text

I am new at coding and I have been trying to look for a solution for this but I haven't found anything so far. My problem is the text shows up outside of the div. [Like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1Q64.jpg)

I have only been able to have the text inside if I don't use border-radius but I would like to keep it.

This is the code:

```css
div.polaroid {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 50px;
}

div.prod-img {
  border-radius: 35%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 0px 70px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 polaroid">
  <a href=""> <img class="prod-img" src="" alt="" />
  </a>
  <div>
    <p>  Name 1 </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide another image of what you are trying to achieve? also a JSFiddle of your code could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

apparently he is inside the div, but for the most part he is being occupied by the image.

You can try to fix this either by the [position property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) as stated above, or if you want to do this in the most manual way possible, you can use the `margin-top` to move it upwards, like:

```html
<p style="margin-top: -25px"> Name 1 </p>
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the easiest solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position:absolute` to take the bottom div out of the normal HTML flow and position it overtop the elements preceeding it.

`position:absolute` will allow you to position the div from the top/left of the first parent div that is not the default (`position:static`) -- *usually, we use `position:relative` as in below example*. If there is no parent div that is positioned relative/fixed/absolute (i.e. they are all still at their default value of `position:static`, then the absolute element will be positioned from the body element.

Together with `position:absolute`, you can also use the css `z-index` to raise or lower an element above/below the others. So, for example, if you had *several* divs that were positioned absolute, you could decide what sits on top of what using z-index.

```css
div.polaroid {
  position:relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.prod-img {
  border-radius: 35%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 0px 70px 0;
}

#onTop{
  position:absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 370px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 polaroid">
    <a href=""> <img class="prod-img" src="http://placekitten.com/250/50" alt="" /></a>
    <div id="onTop">
      <p>  Name 1 </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### References:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-understand-css-position-absolute-once-and-for-all-b71ca10cd3fd/

https://www.lifewire.com/absolute-vs-relative-3466208